# LINQ to SQL Converter

Tags: sql, linq, converters

How can I convert My LINQ to SQL ?

i have this LINQ statement:

```
 int LimCol = Convert.ToInt32(LimitColis);

                result = oListTUP
         .GroupBy(x => new { x.Item1, x.Item2, x.Item3, x.Item4, x.Item5 })
          .Select(g => new
          {
              Key = g.Key,
              Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Item6),
              Poids = g.Sum(x => x.Item7),
          })
          .Select(p => new
          {
              Key = p.Key,
              Items = Enumerable.Repeat(LimCol, p.Sum / LimCol).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(p.Sum % LimCol, p.Sum % LimCol > 0 ? 1 : 0)),
              CalculPoids = p.Poids / Enumerable.Repeat(LimCol, p.Sum / LimCol).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(p.Sum % LimCol, p.Sum % LimCol > 0 ? 1 : 0)).Count()
          })
         .SelectMany(p => p.Items.Select(i => Tuple.Create(p.Key.Item1, p.Key.Item2, p.Key.Item3, p.Key.Item4, p.Key.Item5, i, p.CalculPoids)))
          .ToList();
                }
```

It works well, but somehow want to push it and it become too complicated, so I want to convert it into Pure SQL.

I have tried SQL Profiler and LinqPad, but neither shows me the SQL.

How can I see the SQL code from My LINQ ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: SQL Profiler doesn't show the command being executed against the SQL server?  That doesn't sound right.  What does it show?

Comment: LinqPad for sure [shows the SQL generated](http://tenhundfeld.org/media/sql_to_sql.png)

Comment: You keep saying "My LINQ" - is this MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from MSDN  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb386961(v=VS.90).aspx

Note that in their example, the variable db is the DatabaseContext.